# SQL efficient way to find rows where mobil and mail not in other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to tables with users. Both have one mail column and one mobile column. I have to find all rows in table1 where both mail and mobile is not in table2. And mail and mobile is not empty in table1.

The object is to find users from table1 that doesn't yet exist in table2. And we use mail or mobile to identify them.

I use MySQL

```
table1
|mail       |mobile  |
|a@mail.com |12345678|
|           |21345678|
|c@mail.com |84726287|

table2
|mail       |mobile  |
|d@mail.com |12345678|
|q@mail.com |21888888|
|c@mail.com |        |

Result
|a@mail.com |12345678|
|           |21345678|
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Can mail and/or mobile be NULL? What's the expected result for example if same mail, and both mobile are NULL?

Comment: If mail exist in both tables OR mobile exists in both tables, I don't need that row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find users where there is no mail and no mobile in the other table:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Mail = t2.Mail
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Mobile = t2.Mobile 
)
```

If both must match on the same row it's simpler:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Mail = t2.Mail AND t1.Mobile = t2.Mobile
)
```

Comment: This seems about right. Yes I have to check taht mail doesn't exist and mobile doesn't exist. Many rows have empty mail in  table1, but they can still have match on mobile number.

Comment: question is tagged MySQL lose the pdo database name thats sql-server

Comment: I'm not sure this gives me every user. If I run this, then both mobil phone and mail is filled out in every row of the result. If mail is filled out and mobile is empty in table 1 then I need to get that row if mail isn't in table2

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.mail, a.mobile
from table1 a
left outer join table2 b on a.mail = b.mail and a.mobile = b.mobile
where b.mail is null
and a.mail <> ''
and a.mobile <> ''
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.